# CakePHP logout problem

Tags: cakephp

I have one problem with my website when I click multiples link on left side menu I logged out soon.anybody have idea what is happening with cakephp ? I think, session is destroyed when I click on multiple links.

Help me.

Comment: Your question is not enough specific, mind to share some code?

Comment: His question is plenty specific: in cake, by default, if you have sessions enabled (using Authorize, say) and manage to click two links in quick succession, the session info gets destroyed.

Comment: wow it is scary that a framework would be so flaky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your `Security.level` configuration (in the `app/config/core.php`). If it's set to `high`, cake is going to regenerate the session ID on every request, which might cause the problems you're experiencing. Try setting it to `medium` or `low` and see if it's still happening.

Answer (score 1):

We frequently have this problem too, however, lowering the security level to 'low' sometimes fixes the issue. Currently, I'm suffering from the same problem with the security level set to 'low'

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, no parallel requests are made (as with dynamically generated images). If security level is high, session id is regenerated for every request and therefore you are logged out.